# Minimum Windows XP is required for installing dotnet

Tags: 14.04, 12.04

I installed ubuntu 12 and 14 32 bit operating system and sudo apt-get update and added wine respository and installed wine using sudo install. After that I'm trying to install dotnet framework. But it is showing errors like xmono and I got error that your system is Windows ME etc inorder to install dotnet framework your system should support minimum windows XP.

What would be the solution for this.

Comment: This question is not very clear, see http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
Try to be more specific on what you did to install dotnet and which errors you got. "Errors like xmono" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework does not work well in wine. If you really need it I'd suggest trying one of two ways:

1. Install .NET Framework with winetricks, as described [here on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25478)
2. Install Mono Runtime for Ubuntu, as described [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/), and check if your .NET application starts natively on Ubuntu.